# Загрузка фото из Галереи на Parse.com

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь загрузить фото в parse.com (пользователь должен выбрать фото из Галереи и загрузить в parse.com).
Имею следующий код:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.send_guest_photo);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    Button button_choose_guest_photo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_choose_guest_photo);

    button_choose_guest_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery();
        }
    });

}

public void openGallery() {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
   // SendPhoto();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        SendPhoto();
    }



}

public void SendPhoto(){
    Button button_send_guest_photo =      (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send_guest_photo);
    button_send_guest_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();

            Bitmap b2 = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 1, bos2);
            img = bos2.toByteArray();

            ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("guestsImages");
            gameScore.put("photos", img);
            gameScore.saveInBackground();

        }
    });
}
```

Но фото не загружается. Пожалуйста, покажите, в каком месте кода я неправильно действую?

Answer (score 1):

Загружайте фото как файл.
https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#files

```
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("user_photo.png", bos2.toByteArray());
file.saveInBackground();
```

А потом прикрепляйте этот файл к любому обьекту Parse.